# Error al correr script SQL en MySQL: Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de ejecutar este script, y no me permite añadir las claves ajenas, y no entiendo por qué. ¿Puede alguien ayudarme?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clientes` (
  `numclie` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `repclie` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `limitecredito` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`numclie`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oficinas` (
  `oficina` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ciudad` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `region` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `dir` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `objetivo` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ventas` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT '0.0000',
  PRIMARY KEY (`oficina`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `empleados` (
  `numemp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `edad` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oficina` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `titulo` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `contrato` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `jefe` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cuota` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ventas` decimal(19,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `empleadoscol` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`numemp`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `productos` (
  `idfab` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `idproducto` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `precio` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `existencias` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY `CPProd` (`idfab`,`idproducto`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pedidos` (
  `codigo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `numpedido` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `fechapedido` datetime NOT NULL,
  `clie` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rep` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fab` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `producto` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cant` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `importe` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pedidoscol` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`codigo`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UX_numpedido` (`codigo`),
FOREIGN KEY (`rep`) REFERENCES EMPLEADOS (`numemp`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`clie`) REFERENCES CLIENTES(`numclie`),
FOREIGN KEY (`fab`,`producto`) REFERENCES PRODUCTOS(`idfab`,`idproducto`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=31 ;

alter table `empleados`
add FOREIGN KEY (`jefe`) REFERENCES EMPLEADOS (`numemp`);

 alter table `empleados`
 add FOREIGN KEY (`oficina`) REFERENCES OFICINAS (`oficina`);
alter table `clientes`
add FOREIGN KEY (`repclie`) REFERENCES EMPLEADOS (`numemp`);
alter table `oficinas`
add FOREIGN KEY (`dir`) REFERENCES EMPLEADOS (`numemp`);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sysdiagrams` (
  `diagram_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `principal_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `version` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `definition` longblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`diagram_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_principal_name` (`principal_id`,`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Comment: Intenta poniendo los nombres de las tablas en minusculas.

Comment: Funcionó!! Muchas gracias, no me puedo creer que fuese esa tontería :-)

Comment: No es una tontería, los nombres son case sesnsitive directamente estabas referenciando a otra tabla totalmente diferente. Me alegro que lo hayas solucionado, @iBet7o te recomiendo que pongas tu comentario como respuesta.

Comment: @iBet7o agrega tu respuesta por favor!, aunque no veo donde tiene un nombre de tabla en Mayúsculas ...

Comment: Intenta poniendo los nombres de las tablas en minusculas.

Answer (score 1):

La sensibilidad a mayúsculas y minúsculas de MySQL está dado por el sistema de archivos del sistema operativo. Extraído de la [documentación](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html).

> the case sensitivity of the underlying operating system plays a part
>   in the case sensitivity of database, table, and trigger names. This
>   means such names are not case sensitive in Windows, but are case
>   sensitive in most varieties of Unix.

Por otro lado, ANSI SQL como lenguaje es indiferente a las mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Por lo que surgen dos alternativas:

- Usar minúsculas para los nombres de las tablas y triggers en toda sentencia SQL
- Configurar MySQL mediante la variable  lower_case_table_names para que sea indiferente a las mayúsculas y minúsculas para los nombres de las tablas y utilizar minúsculas para los nombres de triggers

Tener en cuenta que el primer punto puede ser no ser fácilmente realizable con código existente que no tenga presente este tema MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Los nombres de las tablas deben estar en minúscula, son case sensitive, entonces directamente estabas referenciando a otra tabla totalmente diferente.
La sensibilidad del sistema operativo influye en que en mysql las bases de datos, las tablas y los triggers también sean case sensitive.

Por ejemplo, esto no funcionaria:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MY_TABLE.col=1;
```

Por la siguiente explicación:

> A pesar de que la base de datos, la tabla y los triggers no son sensibles en algunas plataformas, no se debe hacer referencia a uno de estos casos utilizando mayúsculas y minúsculas dentro de la misma declaración. La siguiente declaración no funcionaría porque se refiere a una table diferente tanto cuando ponemos **my_table** y después **MY_TABLE**

Te dejo el manual oficial donde se explica esto.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 0):

Los nombres de las tablas deben estar en minusculas, mysql es case sensitive, si pones lo nombres en mayúscula estas referenciando otra tabla.

Por ejemplo

```
FOREIGN KEY (`rep`) REFERENCES EMPLEADOS (`numemp`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`clie`) REFERENCES CLIENTES(`numclie`),
FOREIGN KEY (`fab`,`producto`) REFERENCES PRODUCTOS(`idfab`,`idproducto`)
```

Debería ser

```
FOREIGN KEY (`rep`) REFERENCES empleados (`numemp`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`clie`) REFERENCES clientes(`numclie`),
FOREIGN KEY (`fab`,`producto`) REFERENCES productos(`idfab`,`idproducto`)
```

Comment: Creo que la distinción entre mayúsculas y minúsculas afecta únicamente cuando MySQL guarda los archivos que definen la estructura de las tablas en un sistema de archivos que hace dicha distinción. Por ejemplo, es probable que en Windows sí funcioné aun con los nombres en mayúsculas.

Comment: La sensibilidad al case (? traducción) en MySQL s confugurable. Todo un tema en si.

Answer (score 0):

Me ha pasado algo parecido y encontré el problema tenia un campo cédula en tabla principal y en otra tabla foránea cédula, de igual tipo pero de distinta collation, le cambie la collation de acuerdo a la tabla principal y funciono de maravilla

Answer (score -1):

En mi caso el error es producido ENGINE=InnoDB, son diferentes al momento de crear la tabla con la que se ara la referencia del foreign k